# Get variable from child component with createComponent function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass data from a child component to a parent component but the child component is not called in the HTML part but in the TS part with this function :

```
TextLibre() {
    const cnp = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextlibreComponent);

    const view = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(cnp);

    this.viewList.push(view);
    this.SetLocation();
}

SetLocation() {
    this.viewList.forEach(view => {
      this.render.appendChild(this.textlibrecontainerElement.nativeElement, view.location.nativeElement);
    })
}
```

I would like to retrieve an array of objects from the TextlibreComponent component

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [the documentation] ?

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components

```
  const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(cnp);
  const componentInstance = componentRef.componentInstance;

  const data = componentInstance.someRandomPropertyWithDataInYourChildComponent;
```